# How do I change the CSS Problem with checkout on woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

I have a problem with the checkout pages on woocommerce.
On the billing info page the background needs to be white and on the payment page the boxes are too small
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C65tx.png)
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKBOv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKBOv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VNI1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VNI1.png)

I was expecting the background to be white and the credit card boxes to be larger than they currently are.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to overwrite a template? https://woocommerce.com/document/saved-addresses-for-woocommerce/how-to-override-templates/ their is more information, but also you can play directly with the css but let do first some overwrite of the template and add some class that you can control better.